# I am not able to transfer the data from one page to another using an API in flutter. Its always prints the data which i had initialized

Tags: flutter, api

My code is running fine but it is not printing the appropriate Time of the selected country.
It is always printing  **Delhi and its time only** because I have initialized it in the loading.dart file (`universalTime instance=UniversalTime(location: 'Delhi',time: 'j', flag: 'Flag_of_India.png', url:'Asia/Kolkata',isdaytime: true);`).if I change the city and url here to any other nation in my list, it prints that city's name and time only. It should take the data from choose_location.dart file using the API. Meaning that after running the code the app builds in my phone and if I change the location from the app in my phone to other city like from Delhi to berlin, it still prints Delhi and its time.So its not taking the data from choose_location.dart file when I choose some other location after the app builds in my phone .

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:universal_time_app/pages/choose_location.dart';
import'package:universal_time_app/pages/home.dart';
import'package:universal_time_app/pages/loading.dart';


void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  initialRoute: '/location',
  routes: {
    '/':(context)=>Loading(),
    '/home':(context)=>Home(),
    '/location':(context)=>ChooseLocation(),
  },
));
```

**choose_location.dart**

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import'package:universal_time_app/services/universal_time.dart';
//import 'package:universal_time_app/pages/loading.dart';
//import 'package:universal_time_app/pages/home.dart';
import 'dart:developer';




class ChooseLocation extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChooseLocation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChooseLocationState createState() => _ChooseLocationState();
}

List<UniversalTime> locations = [
  UniversalTime(url: 'Europe/London', location: 'London', flag: 'UK.png',time:'w',isdaytime:true),
  UniversalTime(url: 'Europe/Athens', location: 'Athens', flag: 'Greece.png',time:'w',isdaytime: true),
  UniversalTime(url: 'Africa/Cairo', location: 'Cairo', flag: 'Egypt.png',time:'w',isdaytime: true),
  UniversalTime(url: 'Africa/Nairobi', location: 'Nairobi', flag: 'Kenya.png',time:'w',isdaytime: true),
  UniversalTime(url: 'America/Chicago', location: 'Chicago', flag: 'usa.png',time:'w',isdaytime: true),
  UniversalTime(url: 'America/New_York', location: 'New York', flag: 'usa.png',time:'w',isdaytime: true),
  UniversalTime(url: 'Asia/Seoul', location: 'Seoul', flag: 'South_Korea.png',time:'w',isdaytime: true),
  UniversalTime(url: 'Asia/Jakarta', location: 'Jakarta', flag: 'Indonesia.png',time:'w',isdaytime: true),
  UniversalTime(url: 'Asia/Kolkata', location: 'Delhi', flag: 'India.png',time:'w',isdaytime: true),
];


void updateTime(index,context) async {
   UniversalTime instance = locations[index];
  log('rdygcvjhbnlk');
  await instance.getTime();
  //navigate to home screen

      Navigator.pop(context,{
        'location': instance.location,
        'flag': instance.flag,
        'time': instance.time,
        'isdaytime': instance.isdaytime
      });

   print( locations[index].location);
   print(index);

}

class _ChooseLocationState extends State<ChooseLocation> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
        title: Text('Choose a location'),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount:locations.length,
        itemBuilder: (context,index) {
          print('gintama');
          print(index);
          print( locations[index].location);
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0,horizontal:10.0 ),
            child: Card(
              child: ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  updateTime(index,context);
                },

                title: Text(
                    locations[index].location),
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/Flag_of_${locations[index].flag}'),

                ),

              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      ),

    );
  }
}
```

**loading.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:universal_time_app/services/universal_time.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';

class Loading extends StatefulWidget {
  const Loading({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _LoadingState createState() => _LoadingState();
}
class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {
void setupWorldTime () async {
  UniversalTime instance=UniversalTime(location: 'Delhi',time: 'j', flag: 'Flag_of_the_Germany.png', url:'Asia/Kolkata',isdaytime: true);
     await instance.getTime();
     Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home',arguments: {
       'location':instance.location, 'flag':instance.flag,'time':instance.time, 'isdaytime':instance.isdaytime,
     });

}

@override
void initState(){
    super.initState();
    setupWorldTime();
}
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      body:Center(
        child: SpinKitPouringHourGlassRefined(
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 100.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**home.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:universal_time_app/services/universal_time.dart';
import 'dart:developer';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  Map data={};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    data = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map;
    //data=data.isEmpty ? data: ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map;
    print(data);
    String bgImage='Nw1.jpg';

    //set bg image
     if (data['isdaytime'] == true) {
       bgImage = 'Dw.jpg';
      }
    //print(bgImage);

    //bgImage=data['isdaytime']?'Dw.jpg':'Nw1.jpg';
    return
       Scaffold(
         body:Container(
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
             image: DecorationImage(
               image:AssetImage('assets/$bgImage'),
                   fit: BoxFit.cover,
             ),
           ),
           child: SafeArea(
            child:Column(
              children:<Widget>[
                TextButton.icon(
                    onPressed:(
                    ) async {
                     dynamic result = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/location');
                     setState(() {
                       data ={
                         'time' : result['time'],
                         'location' : result['location'],
                         'isdatime':result['isdaytime'],
                         'flag': result['flag'],
                       };
                     });
                     },
                    icon:Icon(Icons.edit_location_rounded,size:45.0,color: Colors.orange,),
                  label: Text(
                      'Edit Location',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 230.0,),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      data['location'],
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                        fontSize: 50.0,
                        letterSpacing: 2.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
                Text(
                  data['time'],
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 70.0,
                    letterSpacing: 2.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
           ),
         ),
       );
  }
}
```

**universal_time.dart**

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class UniversalTime {

  String location;
  String time;
  String flag;
  String url;
  bool isdaytime;

  UniversalTime({
    required this.time,required this.isdaytime,
    required this.location,required this.flag,required this.url});

  Future <void> getTime() async {
try {
//make request
    Response response = await get(Uri.parse('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/$url'));
    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    String datetime = data['datetime'];
    String offset1 = data['utc_offset'].substring(1,3);
    String offset2 = data['utc_offset'].substring(4,6);

    DateTime now = DateTime.parse(datetime);
    now = now.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offset1), minutes: int.parse(offset2)));


    
    isdaytime = now.hour > 6 && now.hour < 20;
    //Set the time property
    time=DateFormat.jm().format(now);
  }
  catch (e) {

  print('caught error:$e');
  time='could not get data';
  }

  }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In home.dart use .then() like

```
            onPressed:(){
                 Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/location').then((result){
var convertedVal = json.decode(result);
             setState(() {
                   data ={
                     'time' : convertedVal['time'],
                     'location' : convertedVal['location'],
                     'isdatime': convertedVal['isdaytime'],
                     'flag': convertedVal['flag'],
                   };
                 });
             });
           }
```

And in choose Location use pop like this

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(json.encode({
    'location': instance.location,
    'flag': instance.flag,
    'time': instance.time,
    'isdaytime': instance.isdaytime
  }));
```

Comment: It does not fix the issue It gives this line in the console. ```E/flutter (13657): Receiver: null E/flutter (13657): Tried calling: []("time") ```

Comment: updated my answer. please check

Comment: I am getting this error
```59:32: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
                'time' : result['time'],
```

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check

Comment: still the error

lib/pages/home.dart:62:31: Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
                'flag': result['flag'],

Comment: Print result in home.dart and let us know what you get

Comment: Sorry for late response. It doesnt print result because of the above error. I did print(result) in my original code and after running the app in my phone in the chose location page i changed the location to Athens and this came: I/flutter ( 2441): {location: Athens, flag: Greece.png, time: 11:54 AM, isdaytime: true} I/flutter ( 2441): {location: Delhi, flag: Flag_of_India.png, time: 3:24 PM, isdaytime: true} From the first line it seems that the code correctly selects the country and time but later it gets overwritten.

Comment: edited my answer.. Please check. Try adding a json encode

Comment: This error is coming
The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
               var convertedVal = json.decode(result);

Comment: Write json.decode(result.toString());

Comment: hey, i did the above correction and the code ran but still the main problem persists. It always shows Delhi time even if i select any other country time.